# What is wrong with my codes of double datatype maximum limit?

Tags: java, types, long-integer

As we know in Java long datatype take 8 bytes of memory which means that its range should be
-(2<sup>63</sup>) to (2<sup>63</sup>)-1 from min to max. Then I found it using the Java code but I didn't get appropriate value.

```
class limit{
    public static void main(String[] code){
        System.out.println( -(int)Math.pow(2,63));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:- -2147483647

But in a solution of code I found there randomly entered the value of maximum of long which was  -9223372036854775808L.

Comment: Well, for starters, you're casting it to `int` instead of `long`...

Comment: Why not just print the value of Long.MIN_VALUE?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to address the problem that you're casting it to `int` instead of `long`.

Next, you need to do the negation before the cast, not the other way around.

```
public static void main(String[] code){
  System.out.println((long) (-Math.pow(2,63)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value using this code:

```
System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2, 63));
```

You get your output as:

> 9223372036854775807

To get a negative value here, use:

```
System.out.println((long) (-Math.pow(2,63)));
```

Your output will be:

> -9223372036854775808